# what is the better way of describing .SD and .SDcols in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

Please find the toy sample as following.

There should be an efficient way of expressing `.SDcols` and the remain colnames for `.SD`.

In the toy sample, I use `paste0` to simplify it, but at real case, the colnames could be more complicated, is that meaning I have to type all the colnames for `.SD` and `.SDcols`?

Besides, if there are ways to simplify it, can I finish it in a chain of commands? Other than multiple lines of commands, like making a DT with na, getting the colnames, then fill the NA with 0, etc.

Thanks for your advice.

```
set.seed(100)
#data.table with NA
toyDT <- data.table(S1 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                    N1 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T),
                    S2 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                    N2 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T),
                    S3 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                    N3 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T),
                    S4 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                    N4 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T),
                    S5 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                    N5 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T),
                    S6 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                    N6 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T)
         )

#fill the NA in data.table with 0
toyDT2 <- toyDT[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {ifelse(is.na(x), 0L, x)}), .SDcols = paste0("N", 1:6), by = c(paste0("S", 1:6))]

# What if the real world case is like the folling?
# with its own name to describe itself without considering others.

toyDT3 <- data.table(S2301 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                     N7641 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T),
                     S2312 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                     N6582 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T),
                     S2753 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                     N7543 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T),
                     S9644 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                     N2404 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T),
                     S5315 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                     N2275 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T),
                     S6746 = letters[sample(1:26, 50, replace = T)],
                     N0926 = sample(c(1:5,NA), 50, replace = T)
         )
```

Of course we can do this, but just as neat as expected.

```
toyDT[is.na(toyDT)] <- 0
```

Comment: Maybe `grep("^N", names(toyDT), value = TRUE)`, but this is not simpler. (And the same for `"^S"`.)

Comment: Or `sprintf("N%d", 1:6)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks for advice. Unfortunately, it could be difficult to apapt when the colnames are irragular.

Comment: Can you give an example closer to the real use case?

Comment: Please find the edited example as `toyDT3`. All colnames are independent in names, therefore we can't do easy tricks on the names.

Comment: Here are two suggestions. 1) You can use column numbers 2) Rename the columns so that they follow a particular order/pattern.

Comment: Actually, the column names of `ToyDT3` do follow a pattern, And my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558644/what-is-the-better-way-of-describing-sd-and-sdcols-in-data-table?noredirect=1#comment115908035_65558644) above will work.